# Using multiple tables to create a search function

Tags: php, mysql, search

I'm currently working on a project where I'm creating a travel agency site using `PHP` and `MySQL`.

I've come across an issue where I want to add a search function that uses information from multiple `SELECT` options such as *airport*, *location* and *stay length* of which the corresponding information is stored in their own relevant table within MySQL.

How do I querying the database using multiple tables? I've attempted the below solution by selecting each table and column within the table with no success.

```
$location = $_GET['location'];
$airport = $_GET['airport'];
$stay = $_GET['stay'];
$date = $_GET['date'];

$sql = "SELECT location_name, airport__name, stay_length FROM airport, location, stay WHERE location__name =?, airport_name =?, stay_length =?";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
echo $result;
```

**DB Name: Flight**

**Table Names: location, stay, airport**

**Columns**

**location = location_id, location_name**

**stay = stay_id, stay_length**

**airport = airport_id, airport_name**

Comment: You need to learn about sql joins

Comment: What is the relationship between `Airport` and `Location`? Does `Airport` have a `location_id`? Does `stay` have a from and to date? `stay_length` isn't really useful here, but start and end date would be. I assume that `stay` also has a `location_id` or an 'airport_id`.  You need to include all of the relevant referential columns so we can help you with this query

Comment: In your post you should include a plain english description of your query, the query syntax is clearly wrong, but it's not 100% clear what you are actually trying to achieve. Do you want to find all the stays on a specific date that came through a specific airport? provide an example of the parameters you want to pass through, that will help tell your story

Comment: That dupe doesn't help OP, the issue here is the query itself, not the PHP implementation of it